# JQuery change text inside span tag

Tags: jquery

I am running AddThis social media follow widget. After each of the following three icons the name appears in text (via their JS) which I wish to remove.

```
<span class="addthis_follow_label">Facebook</span>
<span class="addthis_follow_label">Twitter</span>
<span class="addthis_follow_label">Google Follow</span>
```

I am using the following JQuery to achieve this

```
<script>
    function test(){
        $(".addthis_follow_label").text(function(index, text) {
            return text.replace("Facebook", "");
                });
        $(".addthis_follow_label").text(function(index, text) {
            return text.replace("Twitter", "");
                });
        $(".addthis_follow_label").text(function(index, text) {
            return text.replace("Google Follow", "");
                });
};
window.onload=test;
</script>
```

Sometimes it does remove the text and sometimes it does not until I refresh the page. How can I improve this script to make it appear when the page is displayed for the first time?

Comment: You may need to set a timeout if there is no feasible way to know once their JS has been executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JQuery code I used worked. After much more reading, I discovered that the change only takes effect after the entire page is loaded. Once the page loads and do not halt midway the code works.

Answer (score 0):

you can try attaching it to [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) instead of window.onload. Or if you are using jQuery, you can use $(document).ready(test);

Comment: Tried this but not working well. Behaves same way as `window.onload=test;`

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at their docs

http://www.addthis.com/academy/using-addthis-asynchronously/

You might find helpful stuff in this doc.

Comment: I tried their refresh layer but it reverses my changes.